# Syntax for outputting raw with 'using'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, authorize.net

I'm implementing AuthorizeNet into my site and as per [[this posting](http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/Trouble-getting-started-with-SIM-in-an-ASP-Net-MVC-project/m-p/16242/highlight/false#M9181)] I am to use something like:

```
@using (Html.BeginSIMForm("http://...", 1.99M, "...", "...", true))
{
    @Html.CheckoutFormInputs(true);
    @Html.Hidden("order_id", "1234");
    <input type = "submit" value = "Pay" />
}
```

the trouble is that the `BeginSIMForm` method outputs HTML which, of course, gets escaped by Razor, so I need to output raw.

I've tried:

```
@Html.Raw(using(html.BeginSIMForm()) { ... })
```

but that's no good.  I can't quite get the syntax right.  is there a way to tell Razor to generate raw output between certain markers?

*** update ***

I missed something which was in the posting.  what I need to do is wrap the call to `.CheckoutFormInputs()` like this:

```
@Html.Raw(Html.CheckoutFormInputs(true));
```

and that produces the right output... however, the call to `.BeginSIMForm()` produces output (a form) at the very top of my page and breaks everything.  grr...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a look at the source code for their helper.  what garbage.  I recommend anyone wanting to implement this service on Razor not bother downloading it.  I will code the forms by hand.  may come back with some code.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the thread you referenced, it seems like that component is not implemented correctly with respect to how it writes the output. You should contact the authors of that library and verify that it supports MVC 3 including the Razor view engine.

Comment: ya.  thanks.  authorize.net is a typical corp.  doesn't want to be reached.  they have a board for the community which is where I've sought help but I won't hold out much hope... was just hoping I could solve the issue with outside help.

Answer (score 0):

I have a detailed answer here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8426501/1087034

I hope this helps.